What is the correct form: 'from app.module.file' or 'from module.file'?
I have been struggling a while with reference in python. Sometimes it works, sometimes do not. I add file __init__.py to all my folders for making them a module. When referencing, for example, a file inside the main folder app, I tend to assume I do not need to reference the root app and start on the main file as from module.file import function, with init inside.
However, When I use it inside a docker file, any reference from folder app, like module2.file1 from module1.file1 outputs No module name module2, even though they are under the same app. I tried using  ... However, I wish to understand the rationale behind these references.
The project runs a cron job of a python script. It scraps a page and download some files. You might read it, but for now, we can assume it just print 'Hello world' on terminal, or something. I want to dockerize it and make it portable.
[1] https://github.com/brunolnetto/RF_CNPJ/blob/f0e9a3fbf59c9db0369ac6d89010e63eaadbea41/Dockerfile#L26

That should not happen if you set the workingdir in the dockerfile correctly.

There is no one correct answer.  It depends on the exact command being used to execute the code, and the current directory, and possibly the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  You haven't shown us any of those things.

Sure. I will. The Dockerfile repository is this one: https://github.com/brunolnetto/RF_CNPJ/blob/f0e9a3fbf59c9db0369ac6d89010e63eaadbea41/Dockerfile#L3 . I usually run docker compose build followed by docker compose up. It should be this simple considering the files work properly outside docker environment, and with adequate docker environment variables, right?! By adequate, I mean ENVIRONMENT=docker-testing, in this case.

That dockerfile does not appear to have any python commands at all, so I am confused how python is even executed here.

I can can explain: Line 25 runs a python script that must run every now and then. In this case, It must run every minute.

Please [edit] the question to include these details directly in the question.

Oh, I see, it creates a crontab entry with the echo command.

The python command is python3 /app/src/main.py, therefore the default module import path is /app/src.  If you write all the imports to be relative to that path, it should work just fine.

The package name that you should use depends on how you set up the folders and more importantly on how you run the code. Specifically, you need to make sure that the "top level" of your import is in the sys.path. There are many mechanisms that control this; the linked duplicate should give enough explanation. It depends, in other words, on whether the "app" folder is intended to contain your overall code project, or the actual package that you want other programs to see as the importable "package".

Aside from that, __init__.py files are not relevant in the way that you seem to think they are, and have not been since Python 3.3. Unfortunately, all the big old popular questions about import in Python are a disorganized mess full of repeated low-quality answers and misinformation. However, the system really is not that complicated, and people keep asking fundamentally the same very few questions, of which your main question is one.

"I tried using ... However, I wish to understand the rationale behind these references." - this is unclear. Did it work when you tried that? If it didn't work, what happened, and how is that different from what you expected?

Really, guys. I just want to make the module reference work. We know, much of these is something silly from my part. I feel very annoying how much must I explain things, when clearly I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I feel very annoying how much must I explain things How do you expect us to help if you do NOT explain things?  Software development is very detail-oriented.
